# exporting man pages to postscript

Tags: pdf, man, postscript, groff, roff

I found that I can save man page into ps format:

```
man -t man > file.ps
```

or to pdf:

```
man -t man | ps2pdf - file.pdf
```

Apart from the man page itself, the export includes man version, page numbers and date.

```
2.6.2    2012-06-18     1
```

How can I remove the date ?
How can I configure what is added ?

Comment: You could edit the troff source by hand before piping it to postscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is set in the source code for the man page

```
-bash-4.2$ man -w man
/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz
-bash-4.2$ zcat $(man -w man) | fgrep 2012
.TH MAN 1 "2012-09-17" "2.6.3" "Manual pager utils"
-bash-4.2$
```

Not portably, as OpenBSD for example instead places the date in `.Dd`

```
$ man -w man
/usr/share/man/man1/man.1
/usr/share/man/man7/man.7
$ grep 2017 $(man -w 1 man)
.\"     $OpenBSD: man.1,v 1.30 2017/08/19 22:05:22 schwarze Exp $
.\" Copyright (c) 2010, 2011, 2014-2017 Ingo Schwarze <schwarze@openbsd.org>
.Dd $Mdocdate: August 19 2017 $
$
```

In either case your options are limited; either edit the source to remove or change the date, or write your own troff parser that does the same.